# Why Google Pay stops working when my app is installed?

Tags: android, nfc, android-9.0-pie, hce, google-pay

I developed an app which has been widely used together with Google Pay application since two years ago and there was no problem with its HCE NFC feature until the release of Android 9.

However, I have received a lot of complaints from Android 9 users recently. They say my app somehow conflicts with Google Pay. Google Pay doesn't work when my app is installed (nothing happens when they try to pay as if NFC is off or blocked). When they uninstall my app, Google Pay starts working again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/servicedesc"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
    <aid-group android:description="@string/aiddescription">
        <aid-filter android:name="F0707070707070617070"/>
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>
```

Note: I used some fake AID in the example above, but I am sure the real AID doesn't conflict with AID of Google Pay.

What significant change of HCE NFC was introduced in Android 9? How can I fix my app?

Comment: Did you add remove something from your proguard-rules?

Comment: @Erik No, I did not. This became a problem after installing a new version of OS, not my app.

Comment: Do you have any stack trace? And what do you mean by the Google Play Store app does not work? What happens when you open the Google Play App? Try clearing the data of your app and then without opening your app check if the Google Play App is working or not?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602  It is Google Pay, not Play. The error occurs when I put the phone to the card terminal.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Do you have any stack trace?

Comment: Try Clearing the data of your app and then without opening your app then try to Open Google Pay? Check if this works or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not a problem with your app but with Google Pay. There is an issue posted for Google Pay not working with Android 9 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132215617

Comment: Yes, it is probably a bug in Google Pay. After installing the latest update of Android everything works again.